# Access 2010: What's the recommended security mechanism to implement user level security over a split database architecture

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I know Access is not the way to go to implement security - but for now, What is the recommended security mechanism to implement user level security over a access 2010 database w/ a split database architecture?
Any comments/pointers-to-tutorials would be appreciated.

EDIT (after the question was closed): 
I am sorry that admins think that this would promote debates. I didn't knew that discussion on security in access 2010 would do that. sorry about that.

Comment: I would not apologize here. The people down voting this question very much missed the basic and simple question. You did NOT ask a open ended question and  you SPECIFIC mentioned ULS. People do not realize that ULS does and can be used in a split environment. As such your question and advice I gave here stands as a reasonable question + answer for the last 20 years of Access. If you had not mentioned ULS and had not mentioned that you realize that such security is less than ideal then posters here might have a legitimate point but as this stands, these people missed the boat on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the mdb format as opposed to the 2010 format, then you can use the built in User level security. As noted this is a file based system, and thus can never really be that secure.

Another approach is to use one of the many free editions of SQL server or even MySql as the back end database part. So you develop in Access, but use a free database server for the tables.

So Access 2010 still does support User Level Security for files, but you have to use + create a mdb file as opposed to accDB file.

And it not clear what you mean by security? For some this means issuing logons and user passwords. For others, it simply means locking up the design parts of the application and restricting users from making changes to the application. Keep in mind restricting changes to the application is not really some kind of "user" security. You can lock up and prevent changes to the application without using the built in security system. So keep the concept of preventing users from using particular forms or tables (user security based on a logon) as opposed to the idea of preventing users from making design changes or looking at code (not user security, but simply a locked down application which does not require user logon's and setting of permissions).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I marked it as answer as I think point that you brought about using mdb format sounds like the way to go. Thanks for the tip. By security, I meant issuing usernames and passwords and allowing users rights to specific objects in access.

Comment: The mdb format is otherwise outdated and I'd think long and hard before choosing mdb over accdb for your database application.